# How can you automate a find-dired query-replace?

Tags: emacs

1. `M-x find-dired`: you will be prompted for a root directory and a filename pattern.
2. Press `t` to "toggle mark" for all files found.
3. Press `Q` for "Query-Replace in Files..."
4. you will be prompted for query/substitution regexps.

How can you define a function like `my-find-dired` that goes through steps 1-3 for you, using in step 1 dir `/foo` and filename `-iname \*.html`, and takes you straight to step 4?

EDIT working on fn def:

I get the step 4 prompting, but it doesn't do anything, because none of the files are marked, so I'm thinking the second-to-last line must be wrong. Here are a couple tries:

```
(defun my-find-dired-and-replace ()
  (interactive)
  (find-dired "~/foo/" "-iname \*.html -o -iname \*.coffee -o -iname \*.styl")
  (dired-mark-files-containing-regexp "\*")
  (call-interactively 'dired-do-query-replace-regexp))
```

also tried just `"*"`

```
(defun my-find-dired-and-replace ()
  (interactive)
  (find-dired "~/foo/" "-iname \*.html -o -iname \*.coffee -o -iname \*.styl")
  (dired-toggle-marks)
  (call-interactively 'dired-do-query-replace-regexp))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling from a program, the approach will be slightly different than using interactive calls. What about that way:

```
(defun my-find-dired-and-replace ()
  (interactive)
  (find-name-dired "MY-DIR" "*.html")
  (dired-mark-files-containing-regexp MY_REGEXP)
  (dired-do-query-replace-regexp FROM TO))
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting "Symbol's function definition is void: dired-find-name". So I changed that line to   `(find-dired "~/parlay/" "-iname \*.html")`, which works, but then I have to fill in MY_REGEXP, FROM, and TO in the defun. Is there a way to have them prompted for interactively?

Comment: `(call-interactively 'dired-do-query-replace-regexp)`

Comment: @Loren dired-find-name was my own alias, sorry. Changed into find-name-dired

Comment: I'm having trouble with the second-to-last line. I'd like all to be marked, but none are marked when doing either `(dired-toggle-marks)` or `(dired-mark-files-containing-regexp "*")`

Comment: @Loren When going to manipulate all occurences of FROM, using FROM as MY_REGEXP would be an option.

Comment: I've tried that, but no files are getting marked, even when using "*" and "\*"

Comment: @Loren `*' is special and needs to be quoted when searched for. Maybe post your code, hard to tell without seeing it.

Comment: @Loren Here it worked like that: (find-dired (expand-file-name "~/MY-DIR") "-iname \"\*.el\" -o -iname \"\*.org\"") Than running the whole thing under edebug. Edebug slows down execution - seems a bug somewhere which forces this.

Comment: @Loren Dired is a tool for interactive use. WRT search-and-replace writing a plain function seems the way to go. See replace-match and its colleages.